# ArcGIS Javascript Legend Is not Showing

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend

I am trying to add a legend, and it gets to the console.log, but it fails at on the line after it.

It does not show any errors saying it failed, but it wont continue past that line.

`map[map_div_id]` holds the map (we have multiple maps on the page).

Any Ideas?

```
//add the legend
dojo.connect(map[map_div_id],'onLayersAddResult',function(results){
  var layerInfo = dojo.map(results, function(layer,index){
    return {layer:layer.layer,title:index};
  });

  if(layerInfo.length > 0){
    console.log(layerInfo);

    var legendDijit = new esri.dijit.Legend({
      map:map[map_div_id],
      layerInfos:layerInfo
    },"legendDiv");

    legendDijit.startup();
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have dojo.require("esri.dijit.Legend"); included in your script?

Comment: Yes, ill add that to post.

Comment: Have you checked to be sure that `layer.layer` is defined?  If the `layer` property of an object in `LayerInfos` is invalid, the `Legend` will not be created and you probably won't get an error message.

Comment: dojo.require("esri.map");
        dojo.require("esri.tasks.query");
        dojo.require("esri.layers.FeatureLayer");
        dojo.require("esri.tasks.gp");
        dojo.require("esri.dijit.Legend");


had to be outside the function .... ><

Comment: Welcome to our site! Please do not alter your question to reflect the solution you found. The best approach is to post your solution as an actual answer: it's perfectly ok for the person who asks a question to answer it themselves. In this way we will have a record of your original question and your answer, which is more useful for future visitors.

Comment: Instead of editing the post with the solution -- it's better to put it as the answer. You can answer your own question.

Comment: Alright will do, 3 hours i have to wait!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to put the dojo.requires outside of the function instead of inside.